# sql server 2008 slow query on sum

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

I am new to having to manage our sqlserver db.  got handed this request.

I have a large table with a million records.  Would like to run this report.   It is taking over an hour using SQL Server 2008.

Rowid is PK and there is an index on dx and varcharfield.

```
SELECT T1.VarcharField,
       T1.DX,
       T1.ROWID,
       (SELECT Sum(t2.QC) AS Total
        FROM   tbl t2
        WHERE  T2.VarcharField = T1.VarcharField
               AND t2.dx <= t1.dx) AS Total
FROM   tbl AS T1
```

Comment: This method of calculating running totals does not scale up to 1 million rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is all much easier in SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT T1.VarcharField,
       T1.DX,
       T1.ROWID,
       SUM(QC) OVER (PARTITION BY VarcharField ORDER BY DX) AS Total
FROM   tbl AS T1
```

As you are on 2008 and the above syntax doesn't work you can try adding this index

```
CREATE INDEX ix ON tbl(VarcharField,DX) INCLUDE (ROWID, QC)
```

And then using the following query

```
WITH RecursiveCTE
     AS (SELECT VarcharField,
                DX,
                ROWID,
                QC,
                QC AS Total
         FROM   (SELECT *,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VarcharField ORDER BY DX) AS RN
                 FROM   tbl) T
         WHERE  RN = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT R.VarcharField,
                R.DX,
                R.ROWID,
                R.QC,
                R.Total
         FROM   (SELECT T.*,
                        T.QC + Total AS Total,
                        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.DX)
                 FROM   tbl T
                        JOIN RecursiveCTE R
                          ON R.VarcharField = T.VarcharField
                             AND R.DX < T.DX) R
         WHERE  R.rn = 1)
SELECT VarcharField,
       DX,
       ROWID,
       Total
FROM   RecursiveCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: This is what worked.  I added the above index.  
CREATE INDEX ix ON tbl(VarcharField,DX) INCLUDE (ROWID, QC)

Select T1.VarcharField , T1.DX, t1.rowid,
 Total = 
  (
   SELECT Sum(t2.QC) AS Total FROM tbl t2 
   WHERE t2.VarcharField = T1.VarcharField 
   And t2.dx <= t1.dx
   and t2.rowid = t1.rowid
  ) 
FROM tbl AS T1 
ORDER BY  DX, VarcharField , rowid

Comment: @kdigman adding `t2.rowid=t1.rowid` would change the semantics considerably.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will run faster:

```
SELECT
  T1.VarcharField,
  T1.DX,
  T1.ROWID,
  SUM(t2.QC) AS Total
FROM
  tbl t2
  JOIN tb1 T1 ON T2.VarcharField = T1.VarcharField
GROUP BY 
  T1.VarcharField,
  T1.DX,
  T1.ROWID
WHERE
  t2.dx <= t1.dx
```

Comment: It will have the same problem as the OP's. Problem is that the 1,000,000 groups will on average each `SUM` 500,000 values. A total of 500 billion values being summed.

Comment: I didn't try but maybe removing where clause and placing that condition in join helps for speed.

Comment: I was thinking that the SUM expressed as a sub-select would be slower than the more direct approach of a grouped query.